# Using flume to stream with average active website to HDFS. Is it efficient?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, flume

Our organization have a very average active website, that would get around 1000 hits per hour. We are planning to stream those logs to HDFS/Hive.

Now the question is around HDFS efficiency around working with smaller files. How ever we see, the filesize that would be accoumulated per hour will not be huge. Hadoop is efficient with larger files. Does loading multiple smaller files into production hadoop system recommended?

What would be impact if the hdfs is cluttred with various small files?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the amount of events added to a file before rolling it into a new file. As stated in the [documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink), this is done through the rolling-like parameters of the HDFS sink:

> hdfs.rollInterval     30  Number of seconds to wait before rolling current file (0 = never roll based on time interval)
>
> hdfs.rollSize     1024    File size to trigger roll, in bytes (0: never roll based on file size)
>
> hdfs.rollCount    10  Number of events written to file before it rolled (0 = never roll based on number of events)

These are defaulted to 30, 1024 and 10, respectively, but you can increase them in order to have larger files (or you can disable some of them).